# How to fix the warning of type casting in 'if let' statement in Xcode 8.3?

Tags: swift, swift3

Consider the following code:

```
let nsdate: NSDate? = NSDate()
if let date = nsdate as? Date { // a warning occurs here
    print(date)
}
```

The compiler complains like this: `Conditional downcast from 'NSDate?' to 'Date' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?`

A cast from `NSData` to `Data` has the same problem. How to fix the it?

Comment: FYI: Swift 3 compiler doesn't complain about your code at all ;-) Should be Swift 3.1 thing...

Comment: The warning will occur after updating to Xcode 8.3.1. I have tried it in playground.

Comment: Why do you declare an **optional** constant but assign a **non-optional** value. That's insane. **Do not annotate types the compiler can infer**. You make it worse.

Comment: Just a sample code conventient to explain my problem. You may see it while dealing with CoreData.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to cast to an optional Date:

```
if let date = nsdate as Date?
```

You're trying to **optional** cast of **optional** NSDate to **NON optional** Date. As long as `NSDate` is bridged from obj-c to `Date`, so this cast always success, so no optional cast required here, just basic cast `as` is enough. Then you need to cast optional value, so the resulting value has to be optional too, therefore `Date?` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.1 distinguishes

- An optional **down** cast `as? Foo`

  It ***casts*** a more unspecific to a more specific type for example

  ```
  let dict : [String:Any] = ["Foo" : 12]
  let number = dict["Foo"] as? Int
  ```
- A **bridge** cast of an optional type `as Foo?`

  It ***bridges*** a (Core)Foundation type to a **toll free** Swift type and vice versa.

  It's the optional equivalent of the usual non-optional syntax

  ```
  let string : NSString = "Foo"
  let swiftString = string as String
  ```

The difference is subtle for the developer but very useful for the compiler.

Basically don't use the `NS...` Foundation classes in Swift 3 if there is a native Swift counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let nsdate: NSDate? = NSDate()

if let date = nsdate {
    print(date)
}
```

The compiler knows it´s an NSDate if unwrapped, so what you are doing is actually casting an NSDate to a Date